# Missing dependency of grass7.2, QGIS2.18 ;r.mapcalculator

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-2.18

I install QGIS2.18 with GRASS7.2.0. QGIS worked well until I was about to used the 'r.mapcalculator' through grass.

I am unable to find it though the 'processing' tab, and type the program states that the plugin is a missing dependency **"GRASS folder is not configured. Please configure it before running GRASS algorithms."**

How do I configure it?

Answer (score 2):

From the main window of QGIS, you need to go on `Processing` > `Options` and then set the path to your GRASS7.2 folder:

[image]